# How to return a value back to the main function from an async.eachOfSeries function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm using the [async npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)  library and I want to be able to return 'someVar' back to the main function, is it possible? The docs mention that it returns a promise if a callback isn't provided. But there's nothing mentioned about returning values from the function.

```
(async ()=>{
   let returnedval = async.eachOfSeries(someArr, async(val,key) => {                     

       let someVar = someFunction();
       ...
       return promise.Resolve();
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this and its working for me. You create a function outside the eachOfSeries and then call that function from within the eachOfSeries by passing in the value you want. The data will be passed and logged for each iteration.

**NOTE:**

> I changed the code to use the empty callback for the eachOfSeries
> function and avoid returning a promise. I've shared the link below for more info on the **async** Docs.

```
(async ()=>{

     //variable created outside the eachOfSeries
     let someVar = [];

      async.eachOfSeries(someArr, async(val,key) => {                     
    
           someVar = someFunction();
           ...
           logPassedData(someVar);
           
       },{});

    //Function created outside the eachOfSeries
    function logPassedData(val){
       console.log("This was passed from within the eachOfSeries : " + val);
    }

})();
```

If you want to know more about the async npm, [Async Documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
> let someVar = [];
> 
> (async ()=>{    let returnedval = async.eachOfSeries(someArr,
> async(val,key) => {                     
> 
>        someVar.push(someFunction());
>        ...    },{}); }
> 
> or
> 
> (async ()=>{
> 
>    let someVar = [];
> 
>    let returnedval = async.eachOfSeries(someArr, async(val,key) => {  
> 
> 
>        someVar.push(someFunction());
>        ...    },{});

}
```

Comment: Though the variable declared outside the eachOfSeries will be utilized within the series function, the value will be 'null' as the main will function execute immediately and will not wait for the async.eachOfSeries to complete, which executes outside of the main function asynchronously. That is why i wanted to know if we can return values once the series has been completed or on each series.